# show data from object on click

Tags: reactjs

In my react app, I'm setting multiple values in an object. I also have some input field with a button/icon attached to it. What I want is, to get the `id` value of that button on click and with that `id` value I want to check if the object has the same property or not. If it has that property I want to use it later for separate functionality. But right now I'm just console logging it. For this I've attached a `handleClick()` handler and getting the `e.target.id` and printing it. But there are 2 problems I'm facing right now.

1. Sometimes I'm getting `empty string` on clicking. Sometimes I've to click multiple times to get the value.
   [image]
2. In the `handleClick()` I'm not getting the data from the object. I've tried using `hasOwnProperty` or `key in Object`, but they are not working

**code**

```
const dropdowns = {
  group: [
    { code: "10202", description: "10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202" },
    { code: "10202", description: "10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202" },
    { code: "10202", description: "10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202" },
    { code: "10202", description: "10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202" },
    { code: "10202", description: "10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202" },
    { code: "10202", description: "10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202 - 10202" },
  ],
  supplier: [
    { code: "3039", name: "3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039" },
    { code: "3039", name: "3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039" },
    { code: "3039", name: "3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039" },
    { code: "3039", name: "3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039" },
    { code: "3039", name: "3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039" },
    { code: "3039", name: "3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039 - 3039" },
  ],
  attribute: [
    { code: "274", name: "274 - 274 - 274 - 274 - 274" },
    { code: "274", name: "274 - 274 - 274 - 274 - 274" },
    { code: "274", name: "274 - 274 - 274 - 274 - 274" },
    { code: "274", name: "274 - 274 - 274 - 274 - 274" },
    { code: "274", name: "274 - 274 - 274 - 274 - 274" },
    { code: "274", name: "274 - 274 - 274 - 274 - 274" },
  ],
  unit: [
    { code: "EA", name: "EA - EA - EA - EA - EA" },
    { code: "EA", name: "EA - EA - EA - EA - EA" },
    { code: "EA", name: "EA - EA - EA - EA - EA" },
    { code: "EA", name: "EA - EA - EA - EA - EA" },
    { code: "EA", name: "EA - EA - EA - EA - EA" },
    { code: "EA", name: "EA - EA - EA - EA - EA" },
  ],
  uses: [
    { code: "1", name: "1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1" },
    { code: "1", name: "1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1" },
    { code: "1", name: "1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1" },
    { code: "1", name: "1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1" },
    { code: "1", name: "1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1" },
    { code: "1", name: "1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1" },
  ],
};


const SetupBar = () => {
  

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    group: "",
    supplier: "",
    attribute: "",
    unit: "",
    uses: "",
  });

  const handleClick = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // console.log(dropdowns.value); I want this
  };



return (
    <div className="parent">   
     <div className="input-fields">
      <label htmlFor="attribute">Attribute ID</label>
      <div className="input-grp">
        <input type="text" />
        <CgArrowRightR
          id="attribute"
          style={{ fontSize: "21px" }}
          onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.id)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
          
        <div className="input-fields">
          <label htmlFor="color">Color</label>
          <input type="text" id="color" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-fields">
          <label htmlFor="group">Group Code</label>
          <div className="input-grp">
            <input type="text" />
            <CgArrowRightR
              id="group"
              style={{ fontSize: "21px" }}
              onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.id)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="input-fields">
          <label htmlFor="supplier">Supplier</label>
          <div className="input-grp">
            <input type="text" />
            <CgArrowRightR
              id="supplier"
              style={{ fontSize: "21px" }}
              onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.id)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The screenshot you have included looks like it's logging out an empty string, not `null`. Does your `CgArrowRightR` component set the `id` immediately? Is it possible there's some delay during which the ID would be unset? (and therefor return an empty string when clicked)

Comment: I tried using `setTimeout()` but still getting the empty string

Comment: you can try to console 'e' rather than 'id', from there you can compare what all you are getting under 'e' when its working and when its not.

Comment: yes, I'm getting `""` in the id, while printing the `e` only...but how do I resolve this now

Comment: sometimes i'm getting the value and sometimes I'm getting empty string

Comment: I think we'll need to see a [reproducing example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), right now the code in the question _should_ work correctly, it might be some other code in the project that's causing the issue, but we can't help with that unless we can see it.

Comment: Share your component `CgArrowRightR` code.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets  `CgArrowR` is just an icon component from `react-icons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `e.target`, `react-icons` SVG also have `path` tag without id and when you click on icon you click on `path` and you get empy string. Just use `e.currentTarget.id` instead of `e.target.id`. `currentTarget` always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached.

Second issue (You incorrect get property):

```
const handleClick = (value) => {
   console.log(dropdowns[value]);
};
```

Comment: Yes...the `currentTarget` is giving the id...but how do I solve the second problem?

Comment: You incorrect get dynamic property, correct will be `console.log(dropdowns[value]);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244912/9294837

Comment: But dot notation is also a valid way to access data, right?

Comment: Yup, if you know property name, you can use dot notation, but if you have dynamic vartiable you must use bracket notation.